# ms sql temporal table find history on column where last changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need a query on temperal table's history table, to find the last time a column value changed and what the difference was vs now. As there are other changes that are also recorded in the table I need to find only the change where to column data changed, then find out by how much and when it changed

my temperal history table looks like this

```
Id     |Price          |LastModifiedDate  |other data
------ |---------------|------------------|--------
696733 |9995           |08/Nov/2016 09:30 |1 -other change
696733 |9995           |06/Nov/2016 09:28 |2 -price change -current price
696733 |10995          |30/Oct/2016 09:29 |2 -other change - prev price
696733 |10995          |29/Oct/2016 09:29 |3 -other change
696733 |10995          |26/Oct/2016 10:10 |4 -other change
696733 |10995          |26/Oct/2016 08:42 |5 -other change
696733 |10995          |25/Oct/2016 10:11 |6 -price change -
696733 |11595          |22/Oct/2016 09:50 |6 -other change - old old price
696733 |11595          |21/Oct/2016 15:26 |7 -other change
```

So id be looking to return 9995 as current price and 10995 as the previous price and the date of change as 06/Nov/2016 09:28  and ignore any other previous price changes. I will need to then filter on the results to check if the change was say 28 days ago so it need to be a solution I can put into a sub query or cross apply

I been trying to use "OVER(order" by to avoid using lost of nested queries

thanks in advance

**Edit**

My sql fiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05db1/7

note sql fiddle doesn't support temperal tables so had to mimic it a bit

Comment: Can you show what you've done already?

Comment: sure, its a long way off though, please see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `OUTER APPLY` with an `ORDER BY` to get the most recent history record that was a different price than the current price (assuming the current price is in the `Pricing` table).

```
SELECT
    p.Id,
    p.Price AS current_price,
    ph.Price AS prev_price,
    ph.LastModifiedDate AS prev_price_date
FROM [Pricing] p
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 ph1.Price, ph1.LastModifiedDate
        FROM [PriceHistory] ph1
        WHERE ph1.Id = p.Id
            AND ph1.Price <> p.Price
        ORDER BY ph1.LastModifiedDate DESC
    ) AS ph
```

Comment: yer I should hve though of using order by

I managed to knockout a sql fiddle example (note sql fiddle dosnt support temperal tables so had to mimic it a bit):

[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05db1/7)

using what you surgested i managed to get the correctg results thank you :)  

out of intrest is there a more efficant/perfomant way of achieving this with " ROW_NUMBER() OVER" or "MIN(x) OVER(PARTITION BY" AND "MAX(OrderQty) OVER(PARTITION BY"

Comment: I haven't tested, but I don't think changing the query to use `ROW_NUMBER()` would be any more efficient, and might end up producing the same execution plan.  And for readability sake, the `OUTER APPLY` makes perfect sense.  I think changing it to use `ROW_NUMBER()` would make it less clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Is there a reason you want to change it?  One thing you can do is change `OUTER APPLY` to `CROSS APPLY` if you only want to return records that have a pricing change.

Comment: ok np just wanted to be sure there wasn't a better way of doing it thanks :)

Comment: In my experience, filtering on `ROW_NUMBER()` = 1 to find the latest/highest/first/last record in each group is very often much faster than `TOP (1)`. But not always. It's worth trying if performance is a problem. However, it makes the query more complicated because you can't use `ROW_NUMBER()` in the `WHERE` clause (in SQL Server at least), so you have to use a nested query / CTE etc.